# Heroku ignores RACK_ENV= staging when uploading assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline

I got 2 heroku apps set up for the production and staging environments.
I use amazon S3 to store assets.
when doing a deploy to production the assets are compiled and stored in the right bucket.
However when doing a deploy to staging the assets are uploaded to the production bucket.
These are the heroku configuration variables for the staging app:

```
RACK_ENV:                     staging
RAILS_ENV:                    staging
S3_BUCKET:                    xxx-staging
S3_HOST:                      https://xxx-staging.s3.amazonaws.com
S3_KEY:                       xxx
S3_REGION:                    eu-west-1
S3_SECRET:                    xxx
```

In the staging app the stylesheets url looks right

```
<link href="https://xxx-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/application-cfddf5f3b9e77c69b3ab4072cc38a7e6.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but the bucket is empty

```
staging.rb
config.assets.enabled = true
ENV['S3_BUCKET']='xxx-staging'
...
```

Any idea what configuration am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a file at `config/environments/staging.rb` that looks similar to the `production.rb`?

Comment: yes i have in that folder staging.rb, production.rb and development.rb. Staging looks similar to production except ENV['S3_BUCKET']and ENV['S3_HOST']

Comment: Which version of Rails? And how are you syncing the assets to S3?

Comment: I use rails 3.2.13. To synchronise the assets I use asset_sync gem. When I run "heroku run assets:precompile --app my-app-staging" the assets are uploaded to the right place (staging bucket) but when i deploy with "git push staging staging:master" the assets are uploaded to the production bucket

Comment: How about the `user-env-compile` labs feature on Heroku? `heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp`

Answer (score 3):

How about the `user-env-compile` labs feature on Heroku?

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked!!!
I just did 
    heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a my-app-staging
and after
    git push staging staging:master 
and the assets are now uploaded to the right bucket (xxx-staging)

Thank you Chris

Comment: I went ahead an added it as my own answer so I can get credit for helping you. :D